# NSNotification stops updating on any of user interface events?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I am using NSNotificationCenter to subscribe to event,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(useNotificationWithLocation:)
 name:@"somename"
 object:nil];
```

And sending from static library,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"somename" object:nil userInfo:dictionary];
```

Everything works as expected, but when I use any of the UI event, like button click, I stop getting notification. I do not have any clue what is happening.

useNotificationWithLocation code,

```
-(void)useNotificationWithLocation:(NSNotification*)value
{
    NSDictionary* dictionary  = value.userInfo;

    CLLocation *currentLoc = [dictionary valueForKey:CURRENT_LOCATION_NOTIFY];
    NSLog(@"useNotificationWithLocation %@",currentLoc);
}
```

Please suggest what should I do about this.

Comment: Do you execute any code that update UI in useNotificationWithLocation: ? can you show that method?

Comment: @Greg No, I didn't. I edited my question with function's code.

Comment: MAke sure that you do not remove Observer any where.

Comment: @keyurbhalodiya No I have not. I am facing this problem since 7 hours now.

Comment: @pranitkothari[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"somename" object:nil]

Pass your dictionary value using global variable

Comment: @keyurbhalodiya No effect. Same thing happening.

Comment: Are you sure that this line have been executed "[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"somename" object:nil userInfo:dictionary];"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55314/discussion-between-pranitkothari-and-keyur-bhalodiya).

Comment: I think your problem with static library code

Comment: Did it solved or not?

Comment: @marceloquinta No. I recreated library by copy pasting existing files, and it worked.